# Snowflake Storage Metrics and Database Metrics

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

is there any way to capture overall storage metrics and database/table metrics in one query.

I have used these views

1. table storage metrics (left join)
2. Database storage usage history

But my overall storage is not matching as per snowflake account

This is the query used

```
Select date_trunc('month',RTR.USAGE_DATE) AS USAGE_MONTH, 
RTR.database_name, ABC.TABLE_NAME AS TABLENAME, avg(ABC.ACTIVE_BYTES) AS 
AVERAGE_DATABASE_BYTES, avg(ABC.FAILSAFE_BYTES) AS 
AVERAGE_FAILSAVE_BYTES, avg(ABC.TIME_TRAVEL_BYTES) AS 
AVERAGE_TIME_TRAVEL_BYTES, FROM 
SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS ABC JOIN 
SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.DATABASE_STORAGE_USAGE_HISTORY RTR ON 
ABC.TABLE_CATALOG = RTR.DATABASE_NAME AND ABC.DELETED='FALSE' where 
coalesce(ABC.TABLE_DROPPES,ABC.SCHEMA_DROPPED,ABC.CATALOG_DROPPED) is 
null GROUP BY 1,2,3
```

Comment: Please add the SQL you are running to your question and give examples of the data mismatch from what you are expecting

Comment: Select 
 date_trunc('month',RTR.USAGE_DATE) AS USAGE_MONTH,
 RTR.database_name,
 ABC.TABLE_NAME AS TABLENAME,
 avg(ABC.ACTIVE_BYTES) AS AVERAGE_DATABASE_BYTES,
 avg(ABC.FAILSAFE_BYTES) AS AVERAGE_FAILSAVE_BYTES,
 avg(ABC.TIME_TRAVEL_BYTES) AS AVERAGE_TIME_TRAVEL_BYTES,
FROM
 SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.TABLE_STORAGE_METRICS ABC
JOIN
 SNOWFLAKE.ACCOUNT_USAGE.DATABASE_STORAGE_USAGE_HISTORY RTR
ON
 ABC.TABLE_CATALOG = RTR.DATABASE_NAME
AND
 ABC.DELETED='FALSE' where coalesce(ABC.TABLE_DROPPES,ABC.SCHEMA_DROPPED,ABC.CATALOG_DROPPED) is null
GROUP BY 1,2,3..........this is the query

Comment: Please don't post code to comments. Use the [edit] link in your question.

Answer (score 3):

You might be missing the data storage for stages and failsafe.

Storage:  Which indicates the data stored in Snowflake tables.
Stages:  Which indicates the data stored in files in Snowflake stages
Failsafe:  Which indicates the storage in the 7-day failsafe area to protect against accidental data loss.

-- Data Storage by Month and Type

```
select to_char(usage_date,'YYYYMM') as sort_month 
,      to_char(usage_date,'Mon-YYYY') as month 
,      avg(storage_bytes) as storage
,      avg(stage_bytes) as stage
,      avg(failsafe_bytes) as failsafe
from snowflake.account_usage.storage_usage
group by month, sort_month
order by sort_month;
```

The report above shows the monthly cost for storage broken by type.

More details: https://www.analytics.today/blog/monitoring-snowflake-usage-and-costs

Comment: hi kayani ,yes i saw this but we cannot get database name / table name along with overall storage ,we are looking for a query where we will get altogether using joins